# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with AVAssetExportSession and AVMutableComposition

Tags: iphone, avfoundation

I'm recording audio separately from building an MPEG4 video on an iphone app.  I'm trying to combine these using AVAssetExportSession.

Audio session is using 1 channel, kAudioFormatAppleLossless and AVAudioQualityMax.  The video is AVVideoCodecH264, using pixel format type kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB.  This video without audio plays fine on my iphone via the photo library.

The exporter is telling me these are the supported presets, I'm using AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality:

```
(
    AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A,
    AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality,
    AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality,
    AVAssetExportPreset640x480,
    AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality
)
```

and it's telling me this is the supported file type:

```
(
    "com.apple.quicktime-movie"
)
```

if I switch to AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough I get file types of

```
(
    "com.apple.quicktime-movie",
    "com.apple.m4a-audio",
    "public.mpeg-4",
    "com.apple.m4v-video",
    "public.3gpp",
    "org.3gpp.adaptive-multi-rate-audio",
    "com.microsoft.waveform-audio",
    "public.aiff-audio",
    "public.aifc-audio"
)
```

I have tried quicktime movie and mpeg 4 as outputFileType and still get the same results.

EDIT: May 10th

Crash was due to a pretty silly error.  I have audio and video now ... sweet!

Key is .mp4 extension, exportSession setOutputFileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie, presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough

Comment: NSZombiesEnabled doesn't show anything.  I will go back and answer some of my old questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My crash was a simple issue.  The bigger problem I had was using the wrong filename extension.  I'm now using .mp4, AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie and AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough.

Comment: Great, glad you solved your own issue.  Make sure you mark the question as answered (with your own answer) so it doesn't show up as an unanswered question :)